# Glossary type facet from Node Index

Tags: drupal, solr, drupal-7, faceted-search, facet

### Problem/Motivation

I am using Search API with SOLR Search API integration. Currently i have one node index showing content type *Listing* and one faceted block attached to it (category). My idea is to create another Faceted Block that will filter by starting letter of *Listing* title.

I think that i have tried everything (then again maybe not...) except creating new indexed field, trimming title to first letter and then using that to filter titles.

Comment: Filter by content type is configurable but if you want to filter by 1st letter of title then you need to do custom implementation.

Comment: Seems that your last approach would complete your purpose with ease. The module doesn't have hooks that I know of that can help you, so you would end up having to modify some SearchApiFacet classes. I've done it and it's not pretty and not good practice.

Comment: Can you give an example ? would help to understand the problem

Answer (score 3):

This solved my problems. Its adding another field to index and you can create facet out of it.

```
function wtc_glossary_search_api_alter_callback_info() {
  $callbacks['wtc_glossary_alter_add_first_letter_title'] = array(
    'name' => t('First letter of listing title'),
    'description' => t("This module provides first letter of title for glossary view."),
    'class' => 'WtcAlterAddFirstLetter',
  );

  return $callbacks;
}

/**
 * Search API data alteration callback that adds the first letter of title  for glossary mode
 */
class WtcAlterAddFirstLetter extends SearchApiAbstractAlterCallback {

  public function alterItems(array &$items) {
    foreach ($items as $id => &$item) {
      if (!isset($item->FIELD_YOU_NEED)) {
        $item->search_api_title_first_letter = NULL;
        continue;
      }
      $item->search_api_title_first_letter = substr($item->FIELD_YOU_NEED,0,1);
    }
  }

  public function propertyInfo() {
    return array(
      'search_api_title_first_letter' => array(
        'label' => t('First Letter of FIELD_YOU_NEED'),
        'description' => t('For for listings in glossary mode.'),
        'type' => 'text',
      ),
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to post your solution to your own question. The only example I could find on the web :)